# Can you stop Alexa Skill session programmatically in lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to stop a session from inside aws-lambda code if you run lambda seperately from skill. 
I am trying to run aws-lambda function from SNS to stop skill session.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've ready my interpretation is that you're interested in ending the session on your Amazon echo by sending an SNS message to an unrelated lambda function.  If that is correct this is how I would proceed.

I have not tried this but having extensive experience with Amazon Alexa Skills in Node.js I would say this might be accomplished in a programmatic way as follows:

1) Enable a dynamodb table within your alexa app. (as seen in line 4)

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = `YOUR_ALEXA_SKILL_ID`;
    alexa.dynamoDBTableName = 'NAME_OF_YOUR_DYNAMODB_TABLE'; //You literally dont need any other code it just does the saving and loading??!! WHAT?
    alexa.registerHandlers(newSessionHandlers, newGameYesNoHandlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Alexa will then create a single datatable row for each unique user.  Note you'll need to set up an IAm permission to allow lambda to access this data table.

2) When your session starts have it update a value in it's own data table row so that `this.attributes['EXECUTING'] = True;`

3) During each consecutive intent call within the session check the value of `this.attributes['EXECUTING]` if the value is `True`, Great, if it is `False` end the session by emitting `this.emit(':tell', "Goodbye!");`

4) Now, the data table rows are indexed by userId.  This will be the tricky part that I have not personally tried.  I suggest creating an intent where the user ask for their userId, then emit a card with the id value on it.  This could then be copied into your own SMS lambda function or some other api.  Alternatively amazon has recently released documentation on how to connect alexa users to your own API's.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/linking-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system

It really depends on what you're hoping the final product will look like.

5) Finally, use your external api or alternate lambda function along with the users userId to access the same dynamodb table and alter the value of `['EXECUTING']` to `False`.  The next intent that is run will then check the database and cause the skill to exit.

Voila!

For more on specific code, account linking, and sms please ask additional questions.  Thanks